# SQLSTATE[HY093]:Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined inC:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler-php\api\models\post.model.php:33

Tags: php, laravel, error404

**Fatal error**: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in
C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler-php\api\models\post.model.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler-php\api\models\post.model.php(33): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler-php\api\controllers\post.controller.php(12): PostModel::postData('usuarios', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler-php\api\routes\services\post.php(33): PostController::postData('usuarios', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler-php\api\routes\routes.php(48): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler-php\api\controllers\routes.controller.php(9): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler-php\api\index.php(18): RoutesController->index()
#6 {main}
thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduler-php\api\models\post.model.php** on line **33**

tengo este error en mi codigo, pero analizandolo parece que todo esta bien, pueden ayudarme por favor.

static public function postData($table, $data)
{

```
    $columns = "";
    $params = "";

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $columns .= $key . ",";
        $params .= ":" . $value . ",";
    }
    $columns = substr($columns, 0, -1);
    $params = substr($params, 0, -1);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($params)";
    $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindParam(":" . $key, $data[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $response = array(
            'comment' => 'el registro de datos se ejecuto exitosamente'
        );

        return $response;
    } else {
        return Connection::connect()->errorInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Parámetro NUMBER no definido... Donde esta ese parámetro? Lo puedes apuntar en el código??

Comment: Pon un `echo $sql;` en tu código y dinos qué muestra. Sea como sea, considera optimizar tu código, eso de recorrer dos veces los mismos datos revela un error de lógica.

Comment: @Excorpion no existe ese parametro, pero no creo que sea ese error

Comment: @A.Cedano esto es lo que muestra `INSERT INTO usuarios (nombres,apellidos,correo,password) VALUES (:jesus joel,:gonzalez
castro,:ieajijfa@gmai.com,:adajdiajdia)`

Comment: La parte de `VALUES` no es correcta, ahí deben ir los nombres de los marcadores, que suelen ser equivalentes a los nombres de cada columna y en el `bindParam` vincular cada valor correspondiente.